# React/Node: Multiple redirects create CORS error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, paypal, cors

I want to implement the Paypal SDK to my web application.

The API connection is managed in an endpoint in the node/express backend. I have to make this axios call from the react frontend to this endpoint which in turn will have to redirect me to PayPal. This causes me to get the error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sandbox.paypal.com . No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I am using the cors package and when I add to the header the PayPal link that the error is complaining about like so:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://sandbox.paypal.com');
```

I get the error like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000 . No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

The http://localhost:5000 being my React client. It looks like it might not be possible to do this using axios call but is there any solution to this?

Comment: This module comes very handy in this case. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: I do have it installed but makes no difference

Comment: Did you whitelist website?

Comment: What does that mean?